# Python subtract time

Tags: python

I have a value from a database that I believe is in a string format "03:00:00". I want to indicate that this is a time value in python and then use it to set a range (ex. from 02:00:00 to 04:00:00)

I've imported the datetime module, but any time I try and perform an operation on the time value, I receive an internal server error.

```
from datetime import date, time, timedelta

time_limit = "03:00:00" ## this is actually received as a get response from JS

time_upper_limit = time_limit + timedelta(minutes=60)
```

The code fails at time_upper_limit. Any idea why this is happening? Do I need to convert the time value?

Comment: firstly I would not use time as a variable name

Comment: Updated. I'm actually using time_limit in the code

Comment: Yes, you need to parse the string into a `datetime` object first. The error message should have made that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot sum a string value and a `timedelta()` object; you can only add `timedelta()` objects to other `timedelta`s, `datetime` objects and `date` objects.

You'll have to parse the time value first; you probably should parse it to another `timedelta()` object (as a duration):

```
hours, minutes, seconds = map(int, time_limit.split(':'))
time_limit = timedelta(hours=hours, minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds)
```

Now you *can* add another `timedelta()` object to it:

```
time_upper_limit = time_limit + timedelta(minutes=60)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> time_limit = "03:00:00"
>>> hours, minutes, seconds = map(int, time_limit.split(':'))
>>> time_limit = timedelta(hours=hours, minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds)
>>> time_limit
datetime.timedelta(0, 10800)
>>> time_limit + timedelta(minutes=60)
datetime.timedelta(0, 14400)
```

The alternative would be to parse this to a `datetime.datetime` object, e.g. add a date to the time; `datetime.time()` objects cannot be used with `timedelta()` objects because they cannot go beyond `23:59:59.999999`, while `timedelta()` objects can easily model periods longer than a day:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> time_limit = "03:00:00"
>>> dt = datetime.strptime(time_limit, '%H:%M:%S')
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 3, 0)
>>> dt + timedelta(minutes=60)
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 4, 0)
```

As you don't have a date component in your string, you end up with the date 1900-01-01 in the resulting value. You could ignore that issue and work with just the time component, or you can use [`datetime.datetime.combine()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine) and [`datetime.datetime.time()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.time) to extract the time component and replace the date with another that suits your needs better (such as [`datetime.date.today()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.time)).