# How to subtract time in python?

Tags: python, time

I'm using Python 3.10 and I'm trying to subtract two time values from each other. Now I have tried bunch of ways to do that but getting errors.

```
day_time = timezone.now()
day_name = day_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
end_Time = datetime.strptime(latest_slots.end_hour, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(end_Time- day_name)
```

**error:** `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`

I also tried:

```
day_time = timezone.now()
end_Time = datetime.strptime(latest_slots.end_hour, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(end_Time- day_time)
```

**error:** `TypeError: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes`

And this as well:

```
day_time = timezone.now()
end_Time = datetime.strptime(latest_slots.end_hour, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.000000.00+00')
print(end_Time- day_time)
```

**error:** `ValueError: time data '2022-11-27 00:00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.000000.00+00'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python subtract time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24973163/python-subtract-time)

Comment: See also [Can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796008/cant-subtract-offset-naive-and-offset-aware-datetimes)

Comment: [How to subtract time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71042018/how-to-subtract-time)

Comment: [subtract two times in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259882/subtract-two-times-in-python)

Comment: [Subtract time from datetime.time object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594164/subtract-time-from-datetime-time-object)

Comment: [Python: Subtracting time from datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46474350/python-subtracting-time-from-datetime)

Comment: and almost 3000 more questions and answers in [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+subtract+time)

Answer (score 0):

Your second approach is almost right, but you should use

```py
day_time = datetime.now()
```

When you subtract you will get a a `datetime.timedelta` [object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

I think the issue with your second approach is that by using timezone you also have the timezone as part of the datetime, instead of just the date and time.

Comment: I still unable to do that. I didn't get it.

Comment: Could you update your question with the issue you get when trying the proposed solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using a combination of the `datetime` and `timedelta` libraries like this:

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
day_time = datetime.now()
end_time = datetime.now() + timedelta(days= 2,hours =7)
result = end_time - day_time
print(result)

# Output :--> 2 days, 7:00:00.000005
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by doing the following approach.

```
        #first i get the current time
        day_time = timezone.now()
        #second converted that into end_time format
        day_time = day_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        #third converted that string again into time object
        day_time = datetime.strptime(day_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        end_Time = datetime.strptime(latest_slots.end_hour, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```